# storm crawler - Technology stack and Apache Nutch

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, nutch, stormcrawler

I want to crawl a particular forum near real time and dump the data into HDFS if not Hbase.

I heard Apache Nutch could solve the purpose but sadly the technology stack it needed is pretty old. I don't want to downgrade the hadoop from 2.6 to earlier version and Elasticsearch to 1.7/1.4 hence i shifted my focus to storm-crawler.

Since I am using Hadoop 2.6, Elasticsearch 2.0 and Hbase 1.1.3, can anyone tell me if storm-crawler 0.9 can be used along with them?

Comment: Why not adding the tag 'stormcrawler' to this question?

Comment: There is no tag of 'stormcrawler' here. I guess it does not have 1500 reputations yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a particular requirement to crawl the forum in a near real time fashion, Nutch is not the best technology to accomplish this. Nutch works on batches, meaning links are generated, then fetched, then parsed, but this wouldn't happen one link at the time. Storm crawler on the other hand is based on Apache Storm, which is a free and open source distributed **realtime** computation system.

Storm Crawler does support indexing into Elasticsearch 1.7.2 at this moment (support for version 2, is on the way https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/es2/external/elasticsearch), no support for indexing into HBase exist at the moment and you couldn't use your hadoop setup because it is based on Apache Storm. Nevertheless Storm Crawler is "A collection of resources for building low-latency, scalable web crawlers" so you can write your own indexer bolt into HBase which shouldn't be too hard, and reuse the rest of the provided resources including the real time crawling that you need.

Comment: Yes i meant near real time as in latency should not be too large. It can be batch also.
Any idea when can the support for version 2.x be provided? Can you give me any example of how to write custom indexer bolt?

Comment: At the moment no ETA on 2.x ES support, but shouldn't be too long. As for writing a custom indexer bolt, the best/simpler example is https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/storm/crawler/indexing/StdOutIndexer.java which just prints info into stdout. Also you can check the other indexers provided in the external folder (aws, solr, sql), usually resources in external have some more goodies, but at least an indexer bolt is included.

Comment: Thanks that helps. 
Also, can it be used on distributed mode rather then on standalone system?

Comment: Glad it helped and yes, in could be run on top of a storm cluster (i.e distributed mode) you just need to package your project using your preferred packing system and the submit the topology using `storm jar` command, something like: `storm jar target/storm-crawler-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar  com.digitalpebble.storm.crawler.CrawlTopology -conf crawler-conf.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

@jorge-luis already replied about ElasticSearch 2. There is a [pull request for it](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/pull/257) and we are in the process of testing it. As for Hadoop, well StormCrawler is not based on it but on Apache Storm - hence the name. Finally there are currently no resources for HBase but this could be added. What did you want to use it for? I assume the documents will be indexed with ES. Did you want to keep the info about URLS in there (like the crawldb in Nutch)? If so then you could also use ES for storing the status, have a look at the [ES module in StormCrawler](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/elasticsearch) for explanation.

Comment: HBase/HDFS is required because I want NoSQL storage/HDFS in the architecture for Predictive modelling at later stage. I would be glad if there is any other way out. Also can you let me know when can you guys finish the testing of 'ES2 Integration'? Can it be possible by the end of April?

Comment: Writing a bolt for writing to HBase would not be very difficult. Alternatively I am working on a bolt that writes content to HDFS as WARC files, which is a standard for web archiving and would be more open than Hbase with a schema.

Comment: As for ES - feel free to test the branch and contribute improvements, that's the best way of making things happen. Just follow the project on Twitter to be kept informed of major improvements.